# Unlock of unowned mutex

Tags: c++

I created the following class which provides an `acquire_lock()` and `release_lock()` function

```
class LockableObject {

public:

    void acquire_lock() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> local_lock(m_mutex);
        m_lock = std::move(local_lock);
    }

    void release_lock() {
        m_lock.unlock();
    }

private:

    std::mutex m_mutex;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_lock;
};
```

This class provides an `acquire_lock` and `release_lock` function. I have multiple threads accessing the same object and calling the `acquire_lock` before performing any operations and then calling `release_lock` once done as below.

```
void ThreadFunc(int ID, LockableObject* lckbleObj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        lckbleObj->acquire_lock();
        std::cout << "Thread with ID = " << ID << "doing work" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        lckbleObj->release_lock();
    }
}



void main()
{
    const int numThreads = 10;
    std::thread workerThreads[numThreads];
    LockableObject *testObject = new LockableObject();

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        workerThreads[i] = std::thread(ThreadFunc, i, testObject);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        workerThreads[i].join();
    }
}
```

In the `acquire_lock` function, I first try to lock the underlying mutex (`m_mutex`) with a local stack `std::unique_lock` object by passing it ( `m_mutex`) in the constructor. I assume once the constructor for `std::unique_lock` returns it has locked the mutex, I then move the `unique_lock` on the stack to the member variable `m_lock`.

This program is flawed in some basic way and during the call to `release_lock` will result in the `"unlock of unowned mutex"`, I seem to be missing something basic about `std::unique_lock` and am looking for someone to correct my understanding.

Comment: You don't pass `std::defer_lock` to the constructor of `std::unique_lock`, so tit's already locked when you construct it. You then try to lock it, which should throw a `std::system_error`. Are you sure this is the code?

Comment: m_lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex); instead of std::move

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are right, I copied some code wrongly into the question. I have corrected the code now by removing the call to lock after construction, now this will fail during unlocking only. Alternatively I also tried calling the constructor with std::defer_lock as the second argument while constructing local_lock and then calling the lock() method on local_lock explicitly but that behavior stayed the same, it runs a few iterations and then errors out with "unlock of unowned mutex"

Comment: @arunsun See my answer below. You also have a race condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my comment about the lack of `std::defer_lock` in the constructor. But you also have a race condition in your code.

The `acquire_lock` function modifies the `m_lock` under protection of the `m_mutex` mutex. Thus, to ensure thread safety, no other thread can modify `m_lock` except while holding `m_mutex`.

But the `release_lock` function modifies `m_lock` while it is releasing that mutex. Thus, you do not have proper synchronization on `m_lock`.

This is somewhat subtle to understand. This is the problem code:

```
    m_lock.unlock();
```

Note that when this function is entered, `m_mutex` is locked but during its execution, it both modifies `m_lock` and releases `m_mutex` in no particular guaranteed order. But `m_mutex` protects `m_lock`. So this is a race condition and not permitted.

It can be fixed as follows:

```
void release_lock() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> local_lock = std::move(m_lock);
    local_lock.unlock();
}
```

Now, this first line of code modifies `m_lock` but runs entirely with `m_mutex` held. This avoids the race condition.

The `unlock` can be removed if desired. The destructor of `local_lock` will do it.

By the way, I would suggest changing the API. Instead of offering lock and unlock calls, instead have a way to create an object that owns a lock on this object. You can even use `std::unique_lock<LockableObject>` if you want. Why create a new API that's worse than the one offered by the standard?

Comment: that is just a typo I believe.

Comment: @David hats off, thank you for the help, that does indeed seem to be the race condition, I am still trying to grok the exact details here but am surprised by how these two operations

Comment: Is my understanding of this race accurate - Looking at the implementation of unlock in std_mutex.h I see that this function first calls unlock on _M_device and then sets _M_owns to false after that, assuming now that one thread is the unlock code and just happens to call unlock on _M_device but has not yet set _M_owns to false, at this time another thread locks and then before this second thread calls unlock, the first thread now sets _M_owns to false, resulting in the second thread erroring out.

Comment: I also spent some time thinking about your suggestions to change the API, you might have a point about the API being un-appealing however I had the following thought process when i came up with it, I have a collection of these shared objects that are being worked on by multiple threads, In my mental model I found it convenient that the lock information lives within these object being locked in order to avoid additional lookup of central lock objects associated with the object being locked. Any suggestions for something better?

Comment: @arunsun I would say that's not a very helpful way to think about it. The way to think about it is simply that you can't access an object in more than one thread without synchronization. Thinking about it the way you suggest leads to the mistake of thinking that when there's no way it can fail that you can think of, that means it can't fail. It so happens in this case that you can think of a way it can fail, but even if you couldn't, that wouldn't mean it couldn't fail.

Answer (score 1):

The member function `acquire_lock` can be changed like below to fix the issue:

```
void acquire_lock() {
    m_lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
}
```

The [move-assign function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/unique_lock/operator=/) of `unique_lock` will be called to manage mutex object `m_mutex` in `m_lock`.

Comment: I believe the other answer was accurate, the issue did seem to be happening in the release_lock() function, however I do appreciate your update to the acquire_lock function which seems to be equivalent to my acquire_lock but with a single line as opposed to two.